# Angular PrimeNG p-tree - How to focus node programmatically by its id?

Tags: angular, focus, primeng, treenode

I have a p-tree with categories.
When I navigate to the categories page with a category id, I want the p-tree to be focused on the desired category.

**HTML**

```html
     <p-tree  *ngIf="categoriesTree" [value]="categoriesTree" selectionMode="single"   [selection]="getselectedCategory()" (onNodeSelect)="categorySelected($event)" ></p-tree>
```

I tried to set a function at the [selection] attr and returning a node, but it didn't work.

**The function**

```js
    public getselectedCategory(){
        this.sortService.CategoryObjectOut.subscribe(val=>{
          for(let i =0; i< this.categoriesTree.length;i++){
            if(this.categoriesTree[i] == val.node){
              this.selectedCategory=val
              return this.selectedCategory.node;
            }
          }
        })
      }
```

For example, if I set the `[selected]="categoriesTree[0]"` it works fine. But I want to do it dynamically.

What is the problem ?

Comment: i solved my issue by adding a global param to the [selected]="categoriesTree[X]" and when i get to this page i send a index number(X) of the desired category.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, to be able to automatically focus on a node, you don't need its ID, in prime ver 7.0.5, you can use the "selection" property and give it the same as your node to focus on.

For more details:

In tree-ex.html:

```html
     <p-tree
      [value]="nodes"
      selectionMode ="single"
      [(selection)] ="selectedNode">
    </p-tree>
```

In tree-ex.ts:

```js
    selectedNode :TreeNode;
    //do something with selectedNode 
    selectedNode = this.selectedNode;
```